# how do i cascade windows in my mdiparent but only to start it from a certain location

Tags: c#, mdiparent

How do i cascade windows in my mdi Parent but only to start it from a certain location.
I have a side panel that I want the cascading and tiling to start next to the panel.

My current code is:

```
this.LayoutMdi(System.Windows.Forms.MdiLayout.Cascade);
```

How do i give it a starting location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.  If you want to give it a start location you have to write your own cascade function.

Comment: i was scared of that:( but thanx